# $A$ is finite, $B$ is NPC - When there's a polynomial reduction from $A$ to $B$?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

> $A$ is finite, $B$ is NPC - When there's a polynomial reduction from $A$ to $B$?

Basically, I've understood that if $A$ is finite, then there's a reduction for every $B$ which isn't trivial (empty or $\Sigma^*$).

BUT, if $B$ is NPC then $B\ne \emptyset, \Sigma^*$, so in which case there's is no polynomial reduction from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: Can you show that a finite language, $A$, is in NP? If $B$ is NP-complete, what does that tell you about reductions from $A$ to $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've confused the direction of the reductions. A reduction from $A$ to $B$ means that you could solve $A$ efficiently if you had an efficient way of solving $B$. It's certainly true that you could determine membership of a finite language efficiently if you could solve some **NP**-complete problem. After all, you can determine membership of a finite language efficiently already, without needing to solve, say, travelling salesman.

On the other hand, it would be surprising if there was a polynomial-time reduction from some **NP**-complete problem to the problem of determining membership of a finite language. That would be saying, "If I could determine membership of this finite language efficiently, I could solve every problem in **NP** efficiently."

In case you weren't confused about which way reductions go, here's a concrete reduction from the language $\mathcal{L} = \{\mathrm{elimination}, \mathrm{computer}, \mathrm{science}\}$ to Boolean satisfiability.  We will define a polynomial-time computable function $f$ from strings $\{a, \dots, z\}^*$ to Boolean formulae such that $f(w)$ is satisfiable if, and only if, $w\in \mathcal{L}$.

```
if w = "elimination" or w = "computer" or w = "science"
    return "X"
else
    return "X∧¬X"
```

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is polynomial since we can just compare its instances with the finite number of positive instances in polynomial (linear in the instance description size) time. *P* $\subset$ *NP*, so $A$ is also in *NP*.

$B$ is *NPC*, so by definition every problem in *NP* can be reduced in polynomial time to B.

Thus, there is always a reduction from $A$ to $B$.

If $A$ is a finite problem or a polynomial problem or even a *NP* problem, there is a reduction. So, in which case there is no reduction from $A$ to a *NPC* problem $B$ ? We know that there is no such reduction when $A$ is an *NEXPTIME-hard* problem, but it's probably also true for simpler problems like *co-NPC* problems.